# Error: Commit and push configuration files to Platform.sh

Tags: node.js, deployment, web-deployment, web-development-server, platform.sh

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXhqM.jpg)

I tried this, but there's an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqN3Q.jpg)

Error message says

No `.platform/services.yaml` file found in the repository.

No `.platform/routes.yaml` file found in the repository.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7r3v.jpg)

but It's definitely there.

i don't understand...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your repository, my guess is that those two files haven't been committed to the repository (the `!` next to each of them in your third image). You can double-check by doing `git status`. If they are definitely committed, hop into our [slack workspace](https://chat.platform.sh/) and/or submit a support ticket so we can take a look at what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you use visual studio and you need to:

- add the files to git
- commit the files to git
- push the file to platform.sh

If you have trouble with this, you may want to use one of the existing template https://docs.platform.sh/development/templates.html and the modify these files.

In general, it is easier to start from a functional solution than a non working one ;-)